# Calling Button Function in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

So I'm trying to call a custom button function for a flip card in WordPress and I'm running into a bit of trouble. I'm sure it is something minor but I've been looking at this too long so I need some help.

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
             <div class="card-container manual-flip">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="cover">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/team/thumb.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="user">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/team/member.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="main">
                                <h3 class="name">Team Member</h3>
                                <p class="profession">Position</p>
                                <p class="text-center">"Some Content Text"</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="footer">                        
                                <button class="btn btn-simple" onclick="rotateCard(this)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i> Manual Rotation
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end front panel -->
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h5 class="motto">"Some Content Text"</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="main">
                                <h4 class="text-center">Job Description</h4>
                                <p class="text-center">Some Qualifications</p>                                          
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-simple" rel="tooltip" title="Flip Card" onclick="rotateCard(this)">
                                <i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Back
                            </button>
                            <div class="social-links text-center">
                                <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end back panel -->
                </div> <!-- end card -->
            </div> <!-- end card-container -->
        </div> <!-- end col sm 3 -->
<!--         <div class="col-sm-1"></div> -->
        </div> <!-- end col-sm-10 -->
```

CSS

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.card-container {
      -webkit-perspective: 800px;
   -moz-perspective: 800px;
     -o-perspective: 800px;
        perspective: 800px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.card {
     -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform .5s;
     -o-transition: -o-transform .5s;
        transition: transform .5s;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
   -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
     -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
        transform: rotateY( 180deg );
        z-index: 3;
}

.back .btn-simple{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 4px;
}
/*        Style       */


.card{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #444444;
}
.card-container, .front, .back {
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.card .cover{
    height: 105px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.card .cover img{
    width: 100%;
}
.card .user{
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    height: 120px;
    margin: -55px auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 120px;
}
.card .user img{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
}

.card .content{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
}
.card .content .main {
    min-height: 160px;
}
.card .back .content .main {
    height: 215px;
}
.card .name {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.card h5{
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.card .profession{
    color: #999999;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.card .footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    color: #999999;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.card .footer .social-links{
    font-size: 18px;
}
.card .footer .social-links a{
    margin: 0 7px;
}
.card .footer .btn-simple{
    margin-top: -6px;
}
.card .header {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    height: 90px;
}
.card .motto{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.card .stats-container{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.card .stats{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33.333333%;
    text-align: center;
}

.card .stats:first-child{
    border-right: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}
.card .stats:last-child{
    border-left: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}
.card .stats h4{
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.card .stats p{
    color: #777777;
}
/*      Just for presentation        */

.title{
    color: #506A85;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 44px;
    margin-bottom: 90px;
    line-height: 90%;
}
.title small{
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
}
.space-30{
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
}
.space-50{
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
}
.space-200{
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
}
.white-board{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 60px 60px 20px;
}
.ct-heart{
    color: #F74933;
}

 pre.prettyprint{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
.atv, .str{
    color: #05AE0E;
}
.tag, .pln, .kwd{
     color: #3472F7;
}
.atn{
  color: #2C93FF;
}
.pln{
   color: #333;
}
.com{
    color: #999;
}
```

And finally my JS

```
function rotateCard(btn){
        var $card = $(btn).closest('.card-container');
        console.log($card);
        if($card.hasClass('hover')){
            $card.removeClass('hover');
        } else {
            $card.addClass('hover');
        }
    }
```

Right now I've got the script in my footer.php file but I am receiving an error that $ is not a function. Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: In your jQuery, try replacing `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: You're beautiful my friend, thank you!